# find a prime ideal which contains $(x^2+1,y^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The problem is :

> check  $I=(x^2+1,y^2+1)$ is not a prime ideal in
> $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and find a proper prime ideal $I_1$  such that
> $I\subset I_1$

I have checked $I$ is not a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

$(x+y)(x-y)=x^2+y^2\in I$, but  $x-y$, $x+y\in I$. If not we can find $f$ and $g$ such that $x-y=f\cdot(x^2+1)+g\cdot (y^2+1)$.We let $x=i$  and $y=-i$ ,$2i=0$.A contradiction.

A similar argument is for $x+y$.

I want to find find a proper prime ideal $I_1$  such that
$I\subset I_1$.

Thanks!

Maybe $(x^2+1,x-y)$ is the solution.

Because $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+1,x-y)\cong \mathbb{Q}[i]$,$ (x^2+1,x-y)$ is also a maximal ideal.

Comment: $(x^2+1, y)$ does not contain $I$. Instead, consider $(x^2+1, x-y)$.

Comment: Thanks!　I get it

Comment: Do we have to find all the prime ideals?